# iptables rule to block traffic not specified in all other rules

Tags: unix, iptables

Is there a way to add a rule in iptable to block traffic not specified/covered in all other rules ?
I know that we can use ! to block specific ports and ip addresses but there are just too many rules in my iptable to individually tackle every rule.

Thanks

Comment: It can either configure in "accept by rules, block any by default" or "block by rules, accept any by default". Common samples, default configuration should have "block by default" at external interface, and "accept by default" on internal interface (or secure interface).

Comment: to configure iptables, you must tackle them one by one. Go ubuntu gufw if you do not want to tackle them.     http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gufw-simple-gui-for-ufw-uncomplicated-firewall.html

Comment: If you are trying to block things you are doing it backwards.  You need to set a default drop policy and then permit traffic you know is good.

Comment: How many rules do you have 1-200,200-2000, or greater than 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your rules with the accept method.

```
iptables -A INPUT <good traffic> -J ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT <good traffic> -J ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT <good traffic> -J ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT <good traffic> -J ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT DROP
```

The last thing drops everything you have not previously accepted.
The setup becomes more complicated if you have more than 1 nic.

To simplify the config you should use chains if your not already.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j input_eth0
iptables -A INPUT-i eth1 -j input_eth1
iptables -A INPUT-i eth2 -j input_eth2
```

etc

Then you proceed like I suggested.

```
iptables -A input_eth0 <good traffic> -J ACCEPT
... 
iptables -A input_eth0 -J DROP

iptables -A input_eth1 <good traffic> -J ACCEPT 
iptables -A input_eth1 -J DROP
```

Additionally these rules at the top of the list will save make sure existing traffic originating from inside your network exists and enters your network freely.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -j DROP   
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules specified by davidgo and cybernard are correct, and cybernard positions them correctly. Let me explain why.

Iptables rules are applied sequentially: from top to bottom. As soon as one is found that applies to the packet in question, the action specified by this "first" rule is applied, ad all following rules are neglected.

Thus, the typical structure of a list of iptables rules includes a "default rule" which is left as last. It is the default rule, i.e., the one we apply when all other rules are inapplicable, thus we ought to leave it as last. If the default rule is a DROP rule, then all the preceding rules are going to be only ACCEPT rules. Then any packet to which no ACCEPT rule applies must be discarded, and this is taken care of by means of the default rule. In other words, if the default rule is DROP, then you only need ACCEPT rules, and if the default rule is ACCEPT, then you only need DROP rules.

Lastly, you can achieve the same aim by using the instruction

```
iptables -P INPUT -J DROP
```

which defines a "default policy" (-P) for the chain INPUT, and that default policy is DROP. It has the same effect as the rules discussed above, but its use is more restricted (see [the Linux man page for iptables here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables))